# Best practice for implementing external Cludo script within Angular

Tags: angular

So I need to implement the following script within Angular. Currently Cludo does not have an example for Angular. What is the best practice for including script within Angular?

https://cludo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021833312-CludoJS-options-Customize-your-search-through-the-script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//customer.cludo.com/scripts/bundles/search-script.min.js" class="externalScript"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" class="externalScript">
 var CludoSearch;
 (function () {
  var cludoSettings = {
    customerId: ID,
    engineId: ID,
    searchUrl: /search,
    language: 'en',
    searchInputs: ['cludo-search-form', 'cludo-search-content-form'],
    type: 'inline',
    searchApiUrl: 'https://api-eu1.cludo.com/api/v3'
 };
 CludoSearch= new Cludo(cludoSettings);
 CludoSearch.init();
})();
</script>
```

Comment: add `search-script.min.js` to angular.json and then expose CludoSearch as a service?

Comment: Could you think of a github example of this?

Comment: So what I am building is a shared library in the end it's packaged and installed using npm install packagename. It does not have its own angular.json.